.NET 8 Desktop ClickOnce deploy System.Deployment error
Publishing the application using ClickOnce works correctly up to a certain point. After installation, the problem may only appear after the next update - randomly. Below is the error log.

INFORMACJE O WERSJI PLATFORMY Windows             : 10.0.19045.0 (Win32NT) Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000 System.Deployment.dll       : 4.8.9176.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B clr.dll             : 4.8.9241.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C dfdll.dll           : 4.8.9176.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B dfshim.dll          : 10.0.19041.30000 (WinBuild.160101.0800) ŹRÓDŁA Adres URL rozmieszczenia            : file:///C:/Users/operator/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Internet%20Explorer/Quick%20Launch/User%20Pinned/TaskBar/eKarta.appref-ms%7C Adres URL dostawcy rozmieszczenia       : file://-/APPS/eKarta2.0/e-karta.application PODSUMOWANIE BŁĘDÓW Poniżej znajduje się podsumowanie błędów. Szczegółowe informacje na temat tych błędów znajdują się w dalszej części dziennika. * Aktywacja aplikacji C:\Users\operator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\eKarta.appref-ms| spowodowała wyjątek. Wykryto następujące komunikaty o niepowodzeniach: + Wartość jest spoza oczekiwanego zakresu. PODSUMOWANIE NIEPOWODZEŃ TRANSAKCJI MAGAZYNOWANIA SKŁADNIKÓW Nie wykryto błędów transakcji. OSTRZEŻENIA * Manifest tej aplikacji nie ma podpisu. Sprawdzanie poprawności podpisu zostanie zignorowane. STAN POSTĘPU OPERACJI * [10.06.2024 07:48:21] : Rozpoczęto aktywację C:\Users\operator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\eKarta.appref-ms|. * [10.06.2024 07:48:21] : Wykonywanie niezbędnego sprawdzenia aktualizacji zgodnie z rozmieszczeniem. SZCZEGÓŁY BŁĘDÓW Podczas tej operacji zostały wykryte następujące błędy. * [10.06.2024 07:48:21] System.ArgumentException - Wartość jest spoza oczekiwanego zakresu. - Źródło: System.Deployment - Ślad stosu: w System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation) w System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter) w System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter) w System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter) w System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ProcessOrFollowShortcut(String shortcutFile, String& errorPageUrl, TempFile& deployFile) w System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri) w System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl) --- Koniec śladu stosu z poprzedniej lokalizacji, w której wystąpił wyjątek --- w System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() w System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl) w System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state) SZCZEGÓŁY TRANSAKCJI MAGAZYNOWANIA SKŁADNIKÓW Brak dostępnych informacji o transakcji.

Google translated to English:

PLATFORM VERSION INFORMATION Windows : 10.0.19045.0 (Win32NT) Common Language Runtime : 4.0.30319.42000 System.Deployment.dll : 4.8.9176.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B clr.dll : 4.8.9241.0 built by: NET481R EL1LAST_C dfdll.dll : 4.8.9176.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B dfshim.dll : 10.0.19041.30000 (WinBuild.160101.0800) SOURCES Deployment URL : file:///C:/Users/operator/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Internet%20Explorer/Quick%20Launch/User%20Pin ned /TaskBar/eKarta.appref-ms%7C Placement Provider URL : file://-/APPS/eKarta2.0/e-karta.application ERROR SUMMARY Below is a summary of the errors. Details about these errors are provided later in the log. * Application activation C:\Users\operator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\eKarta.appref-ms| caused an exception. The following failure messages were detected: + The value is outside the expected range. COMPONENT STORAGE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY No transaction failures detected. WARNINGS * The manifest for this application has no signature. Signature validation will be ignored. OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS * [10/06/2024 07:48:21] : Activation started C:\Users\operator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\eKarta.appref-ms|. * [10/06/2024 07:48:21] : Performing necessary update check as deployed. ERROR DETAILS The following errors were detected during this operation. * [10/06/2024 07:48:21] System.ArgumentException - Value is outside the expected range. - Source: System.Deployment - Stack Trace: in System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation) in System.Deployment .Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter) at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter) at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId app Id, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter) at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ProcessOrFollowShortcut(String shortcutFile, String& errorPageUrl, TempFile& deployFile) at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, St ring textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri) in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& error PageUrl) --- End of stack trace from previous location, in which the exception performed --- in System.runtime.ExceptServices.Exceptdispatchinfo.throw () in System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationAtivator. ING Deploymentprovideerurlfromextension, Browsersettings Browsersettings, String & ERRORPAGEURL) in System .Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state) COMPONENT STORAGE TRANSACTION DETAILS No transaction information available.

I modified the publication settings in various ways - each time after changing and reinstalling, the application works for a few updates.

You could make that error log far easier to read than that. I haven't read it and won't as it is and I suspect others may be the same.

Finally I figured out what's happening.
The error occurs when the application has an update to install and the user starts the process twice. I simulated double-clicking the icon on the taskbar, but it can also happen in other ways. The update is found and installed, but after the process, the above error occurs and the application can no longer be launched at all.
